# Unable to add new environment variable to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

When trying to add a new environment variable to our stack with Elastic Beanstalk we got an error:

> Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Template format error: Parameter
>   'EnvironmentVariables' default value '[...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Update 15/12/2016] Looks like the initial source link is not valid anymore but the answer is still true.

> You can include as many properties as you want, but the total size of all properties cannot exceed 4096 bytes. You can delete a variable by leaving the value blank.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-setenv.html

> The combined size of all environment variables defined for an
>   environment is limited to 4096 bytes. The format of environment
>   variables is KEY1=VALUE1, KEY2=VALUE2, which means that both the value
>   and key of each variable are included in the total. When a platform
>   has one or more predefined environment variables, such as
>   JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING those variables are also included in the total.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html